# The local variable action may not have been initialized?

Tags: java, variables, compiler-errors

I get the error "The local variable action may not have been initialized" on the last 6 if statements. I don't know what it wants from me. Please help! :( I have tried the eclipse suggested fixes and tried to fix it on my own and nothing works...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class test2 {

enum dog {sleeping, eating, peeing, pooping, dead, robot}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    dog action;
    int heartrate;

    out.println("What is the heart rate of your dog? I will be able to tell you what the dog is doing from that information.");
    heartrate = myScanner.nextInt();

    if (heartrate >= 60 || heartrate <= 120) {
        action = dog.sleeping;
    }else if (heartrate == 0) {
        action = dog.dead;
    }else if (heartrate > 500) {
        action = dog.robot;
    }else if (heartrate >= 150 || heartrate <= 200) {
        action = dog.peeing;
    }else if (heartrate >= 150 || heartrate <= 200) {
        action = dog.pooping;
    }else if (heartrate >= 150 || heartrate <= 200) {
        action = dog.eating;
    }
    out.print("Your dog is currently ");
    if (action == dog.sleeping) {
        out.print("sleeping ");
    }
    if (action == dog.dead) {
        out.print("dead ");
    }
    if (action == dog.robot) {
        out.print("a robot.");
    }
    if (action == dog.peeing) {
        out.print("peeing ");
    }
    if (action == dog.pooping) {
        out.print("pooping ");
    }
    if (action == dog.eating) {
        out.print("eating ");
    }
    System.out.println(".");
}
}
```

Comment: It wants to to *ensure* `action` was initialized, which you have not.

Comment: **Read the error message.** You need to make sure that your code assigns a value to `action`.

Comment: `if (heartrate >= 60 || heartrate <= 120)` implies that a sleeping dog can have a negative heart rate ... maybe you wanted `&&` for `is between x and y` instead of `||`

Comment: The condition `heartrate >= 150 || heartrate <= 200` (and several others like this) can be replaced with `true`  -- insofar, the compiler is atually wrong, this program will indeed assign action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid 'the local variable may not have been initialized'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585513/how-to-avoid-the-local-variable-may-not-have-been-initialized)

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the variable a value before you use it.  For example `action` is not initialised under all conditions so you cannot safely use it.

A simple solution is to give a default value like

```
dog action = dog.dead;
```

Instead of a series of `if(action ==` statements you could use one `switch` block.

BTW Three of your conditions are the same, your IDE should warn you of this too.