# Local variable may not have been initialized

Tags: java, while-loop, double

### Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double rand = 0;
        while (rand == rand) {
            double rand1 = Math.random();
            String x1 = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, rand1 + x1);
            if (x1.equals("exit")) {
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, x1);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

### Error:

> The local variable x1 may not have been initialized

at line 9

> String x1 = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, rand1 + x1);

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid 'the local variable may not have been initialized'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585513/how-to-avoid-the-local-variable-may-not-have-been-initialized)

Answer (score 2):

When you do an assignment, the *right-hand part* of that assignment is evaluated *first*, so it first will evaluate

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, rand1 + x1);
```

at that moment, `x1`has not been initialized nor declared. Therefore, you cannot use it. After the *right-hand part* gets evaluated, then its result is assigned to the *left-hand part*:

```
String x1 = result;
```

**How to fix it?** One simple way, would be deleting `x1` so you get

```
String x1 = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, rand1);
```

**Notes:**

- You may want to check that loop condition `while (rand == rand)`

Answer (score 1):

You can not declare a variable and use it from same line:

```
String x1 = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, rand1 + x1);
                                                                   ^ here
```

Comment: what should I do instead

Comment: @user3449760 Declare `String x2 = "some value"` before that line. and pass replace with that `x1`

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use `x1` before it was even assigned a value.
You could, for example, initialize it to an empty `string`. e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double rand = 0;
    String x1 = ""; // first initialization
    while (rand == rand) {
        double rand1 = Math.random();
        x1 = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, rand1 + x1);
        if (x1.equals("exit")) {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, x1);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```