# "The Local variable 'name' may not have been initialized" error

Tags: java, project

I keep getting this 
 **`"The Local variable oppMove may not have been initialized"`** Error which seems to be the only thing keeping me from really testing. I can't figure out why it might not initialize (at least with my knowledge of programming).

**Maxit class**

```
import java.util.*;

/* Encapsulates a position in a game of Maxit.  It is assumed that (1) the
 * upper left hand corner is the initial pivot, (2) the first player adds
 * worths and tries to maximize the sum, and (3) the second player subtracts
 * worths and tries to minimize the sum. */
public class Maxit
{
  //*************************************************************************
  // Public Constants
  //*************************************************************************
  public static final int HUMAN = 1;
  public static final int COMPUTER = 2;
  public static final int EMPTY = 0; 

  public static final int HUMAN_WINS = 0;
  public static final int DRAW = 1;
  public static final int UNCLEAR = 2;
  public static final int COMPUTER_WINS = 3;

  //*************************************************************************
  // Private Properties
  //*************************************************************************
  // int [r][c] board where r is the rows and c is the columns
  private int [][] board;

  //*************************************************************************
  // Public Properties
  //*************************************************************************
  public int human_score = 0;
  public int computer_score = 0;
  public int current_column = 0;
  public int current_row = 0;
  public int current_turn = 0;


   /* Construct a Maxit board with the specified worths, which are assumed to
    * be in a square matrix. */
  public Maxit ()
  {
    constructBoard(3);
  }

    public Maxit (int n)
  {
    constructBoard(n);
  }

   public Maxit( int [][] worths )
   {
     board = worths;
   }

   /* Return best move. */
   public Move bestMove()
   {
     int side = current_turn++;
     if(current_turn > COMPUTER)
       current_turn = HUMAN;
     return chooseBestMove( side, current_row, current_column );
   }


   private Move chooseBestMove( int side, int starting_row, int starting_column )
   {
        // count++;              // For timing
        int opp;              // The other side
        Move oppMove;         // Opponent's best reply
        int simpleEval;       // Result of an immediate evaluation
        int bestRow = 0;
        int bestColumn = 0;
        int check;

        if( ( simpleEval = positionValue( ) ) != UNCLEAR ) 
        {
            return new Move( simpleEval );
        }

        if( side == COMPUTER )
        {
            opp = HUMAN; check = HUMAN_WINS;
        }
        else
        {
            opp = COMPUTER; check = COMPUTER_WINS;
        }

        for( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++)
        {
          for( int column = 0; column < board.length; column++)
          {
            if (squareContains(row, starting_column) && column == starting_column)
            {
              int n = board[row][starting_column];
              choose(row, current_column, EMPTY);
              oppMove = chooseBestMove( opp , row, starting_column);
              choose(row, starting_column, n);
            }
            else if (squareContains(starting_row, column) && row == starting_row)
            {
              int n = board[starting_row][column];
              choose(starting_row, column, EMPTY);
              oppMove = chooseBestMove( opp , starting_row, column);
              choose(starting_row, column, n);
            }

            if( side == COMPUTER && oppMove.value < check
                   ||  side == HUMAN && oppMove.value > check )
            {
              check = oppMove.value;
              bestRow = row; bestColumn = column; current_row = row; current_column = column;
            }
          }
        }

      return new Move( check, bestRow, bestColumn );
   }


  //*************************************************************************
  // Standard Accessors
  //*************************************************************************

    /** Return who has captured the row r, column c square. */
    public int getSquare(int r, int c)
    {
        return board[r][c];
    }

   /* Return score. */
   public int getScore()
   {
      return human_score - computer_score;
   }

   /* */
   public boolean isTheEnd()
   {
     int row_count = 0;
     int column_count = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
     {
       if(board[current_row][i] == EMPTY)
         column_count++;
       if(board[i][current_column] == EMPTY)
         row_count++;
     }
     if(column_count == board.length && row_count == board.length)
     {return true;}
     else
     {return false;}
   }

   /* */
   public int whoWins()
   {
     if (getScore() >= 1)
       return HUMAN_WINS;
     else if (getScore() <= -1)
       return COMPUTER_WINS;
     else
       return DRAW;
   }

   /** Return string representation of the board. */
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < board.length; c++) {
                s += squareContains(r, c) ? "" + board[r][c] :
                    "_";
            }
            if (r < board.length) s += "\n";
        }
        return s;
    }

   /* */
   public void constructBoard(int n)
   {
     board = new int[n][n];
     int stuff = 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
     {
       board[i][j] = stuff++;
     }

     int columns = board[0].length;
     ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     //System.out.println("TestA");

     for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
     {
       for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
       {
         //System.out.println("Test" + (i + j + 1));
         arr.add(board[i][j]);
       }
     }
     //System.out.println("TestB");
     Collections.shuffle(arr);
     int count = 0; //needed to get the number back from arr.
     for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
     {
       for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
       {
         //System.out.println("Test" + (i + j + 1));
         board[i][j] = arr.get(count);
         count += 1;
       }
     }
   }

  //*************************************************************************
  // Standard Mutators
  //*************************************************************************
   /* Return true and play the specified move if it is legal;
    * otherwise, return false. */
   public boolean tryMove(Move move)
   {
     if ( move.row < 0 || move.row > board.length || move.column < 0 
           || move.column > board[0].length || !squareContains(move.row,
                                                               move.column))
       if(move.row != current_row || move.column != current_column) {return false;}

     if(current_turn == HUMAN)
       human_score += board[move.row][move.column];
     else { computer_score += board[move.row][move.column]; }

     board[move.row][move.column] = EMPTY;
     return true; 
   }

   /* */
   private int positionValue( )
   {
     if (isTheEnd())
       return whoWins();
     else
       return UNCLEAR;
   }

   /* */
    public void clearBoard( )
    {
        constructBoard(board.length);
    }

  //*************************************************************************
  // Private Methods
  //*************************************************************************
   private boolean squareContains(int row, int column)
   {
     return board[row][column] != EMPTY;
   }

   private void choose(int row, int column, int value)
   {
     board[ row ][ column ] = value;
   }
}
```

**Move class**

```
/* Encapsulate a row, column, and value of a move.  If only the
 * row and column are known, then the value is null.  If only
 * the value is known (e.g., at the end of the game when no move
 * is possible), then row and column are -1. */
public final class Move
{
  public int row;
  public int column;
  public Integer value;

  public Move(int v)
  { this( v, -1, -1 ); }

  public Move(int r, int c)
  { this( null, r, c ); }      

  public Move(Move original)
  { this(original.value, original.row, original.column); }

  public Move(Integer v, int r, int c)
  { value = v; row = r; column = c; }

  public String toString()
  {
    return "(" + row + ", " + column + ", " + value + ")";
  }

  public boolean equals(Object other)
  {
    if (other == null || !(other instanceof Move)) return false;
    Move that = (Move)other;
    if (row != that.row || column != that.column) return false;
    if (value == null) return that.value == null;
    return value.equals(that.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us the exact line number where the error occurs.

Comment: You have no idea how much it pains me to see a `s +=` for a String in a loop or those final static ints instead of an enum.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid 'the local variable may not have been initialized'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585513/how-to-avoid-the-local-variable-may-not-have-been-initialized)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Move oppMove;         // Opponent's best reply
```

to

```
Move oppMove = null;         // Opponent's best reply
```

This will fail fast, because your code doesn't seem to always initialize `oppMove` but you access it anyway. You should check that it isn't `null` first

```
side == COMPUTER && oppMove.value < check
```

as

```
oppMove != null && side == COMPUTER && oppMove.value < check
```

Comment: Sweet! That fixed that problem. There are other things wrong but that's not breaking it now.

Answer (score 1):

To explain why this error is occurring a bit more here is your code:

```
int opp;              // The other side
    Move oppMove;         // Opponent's best reply
    int simpleEval;       // Result of an immediate evaluation
    int bestRow = 0;
    int bestColumn = 0;
    int check;

    if( ( simpleEval = positionValue( ) ) != UNCLEAR ) 
    {
        return new Move( simpleEval );
    }

    if( side == COMPUTER )
    {
        opp = HUMAN; check = HUMAN_WINS;
    }
    else
    {
        opp = COMPUTER; check = COMPUTER_WINS;
    }

    for( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++)
    {
      for( int column = 0; column < board.length; column++)
      {
        if (squareContains(row, starting_column) && column == starting_column)
        {
          int n = board[row][starting_column];
          choose(row, current_column, EMPTY);
          oppMove = chooseBestMove( opp , row, starting_column);
          choose(row, starting_column, n);
        }
        else if (squareContains(starting_row, column) && row == starting_row)
        {
          int n = board[starting_row][column];
          choose(starting_row, column, EMPTY);
          oppMove = chooseBestMove( opp , starting_row, column);
          choose(starting_row, column, n);
        }

        if( side == COMPUTER && oppMove.value < check
               ||  side == HUMAN && oppMove.value > check )
        {
          check = oppMove.value;
          bestRow = row; bestColumn = column; current_row = row; current_column = column;
        }
      }
    }
```

As you can see above, the line Move oppMove declares the variable. This would be fine if it was somewhere given a value before being use. The two places where it is possible to receive a value is:

```
if (squareContains(row, starting_column) && column == starting_column)
        {
          int n = board[row][starting_column];
          choose(row, current_column, EMPTY);
          oppMove = chooseBestMove( opp , row, starting_column);
          choose(row, starting_column, n);
        }
```

AND

```
else if (squareContains(starting_row, column) && row == starting_row)
        {
          int n = board[starting_row][column];
          choose(starting_row, column, EMPTY);
          oppMove = chooseBestMove( opp , starting_row, column);
          choose(starting_row, column, n);
        }
```

Because these conditions do not cover every possible route the program code can take, you can still not use this variable yet. However,

```
if( side == COMPUTER && oppMove.value < check
               ||  side == HUMAN && oppMove.value > check )
```

this conditional will return an error because the variable oppMove has still not be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
Move oppMove;         // Opponent's best reply
```

to

```
Move oppMove = null;         // Opponent's best reply
```

Comment: This will cause a NPE when neither `squareContains(row, starting_column) && column == starting_column` nor `squareContains(starting_row, column) && row == starting_row` is true.

Answer (score 0):

It expects you to initialize it. You can initialize it to `null` if you don't have any initial values for it. Like;

```
Move oppMove = null;
```

Comment: This will cause a NPE in the case neither `squareContains(row, starting_column) && column == starting_column` nor `squareContains(starting_row, column) && row == starting_row` is true.

Comment: You are absolutely true I only gave the simplest solution to avoid from the compilation error. Testing should be made by him.

Answer (score 0):

Since `oppMove` is only initialized when certain 'if' conditions are met, the compiler is warning you of this uninitialized value.

Initializing to null should fix this issue though you should make sure that doesnt throw NPE for cases where it is still remains assigned to `null`

Comment: What will happen when the *next* if statement of `side == COMPUTER && oppMove.value < check || side == HUMAN && oppMove.value > check` is run then?  (which also likely has a bug in it)