# Local variable may not have been initialized in my For loop

Tags: java

Trying to make a for loop where a user inputs 6 numbers. Then each number is validated to see that it is positive. Then they are all added up for a subtotal.

On my last line `count += itemPrice;` I'm getting an error on `count` saying "The local variable may not have been initialized." A buddy of mine can't seem to figure out why as well and wondering what is up with that.

```
public static double namehere() {
double count;
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Price of Item: ");
    double itemPrice = input.nextDouble();
    while (itemPrice < 0.01)
    {
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Price of Item: ");
        itemPrice = input.nextDouble();
    }
    count += itemPrice;
}
```

Comment: You need to give default value to your count. Here I would suggest 0.

Comment: Your method needs a return statement on top of `count` needing a default value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid 'the local variable may not have been initialized'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585513/how-to-avoid-the-local-variable-may-not-have-been-initialized)

Comment: @DrewKennedy : whole method isn't shown so I guess in the end there is the return value. But true it's not easy to tell when code not indented correctly

Comment: @realUser404 Yeah I figured as much - better to go off of what is shown than make assumptions in my eyes.

Answer (score 3):

```
double count;      // not initialized

double count = 0;  // initialized
```

Local primitive variables are not set to 0 by default, so they must be explicitly initialized.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, your `count` variable is not initialized. To solve the error, initialize with a default value, like `0`.

Note: the local variables are not initialized implicitly not like class members.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of local variables is different than the purpose of instance variables. Local variables are there to be used as part of a calculation; instance variables are there to contain state. If you use a local variable without assigning it a value, that's almost certainly a logic error, and hence, compiler complains..

Comment: If it was instance variable there would be an error too if not initialized

Comment: No, in case of instance variable, there would not be any errors as JVM initialises all the instance variables when an object gets created.